# onClick javascript: navigation with changing css background images / two types

Tags: javascript, css, onclick

i am doing a site with 2 navigations (navs) including links, each of them in another div.

When a link is clicked it should change its background image in the css (change class).
And only one link of its class can change the background.

In the second nav there is one link which is also included in nav 1.
Also are in the second nav two different background images to "toggle".

I already have accomplished the first nav, but I do not know how to include the second one.
In the second one is the problem that two links should not change their background at the same time.

The site: http://enlifer.de/test25/zp-kazachkova.html

The second nav is at the height of the logo.
If "Leistungen" is clicked in the second nav, the first one should also change its default background and vice versa.

Following code is relevant.

**First nav**

```
<navigation>
    <ul id="nav">

        <li class="link" onclick="mark(this)">  <a href="#" class="textlink">Kontakt</a>    </li>
        <li class="link" onclick="mark(this)">  <a href="#" class="textlink">Anfahrt</a>    </li>
        <li class="link" onclick="mark(this)">  <a href="#" class="textlink">Leistungen</a> </li>
        <li class="link" onclick="mark(this)">  <a href="#" class="textlink">Praxisteam</a> </li>

    </ul>

</navigation>
```

**Second nav**

```
<up>
    <ul id="up">

        <li class="uplink-l" onclick="l_mark(this)">    <a href="#" class="uptextlink-l">Leistungen</a> </li>
        <li class="uplink-i" onclick="i_mark(this)">    <a href="#" class="uptextlink-i">Impressum</a>  </li>

    </ul>

</up>
```

***JavaScript***

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function mark(cell)
{
for(i=0; i <
document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("li").length; i++)
{
document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("li")[i].className="link";
}
cell.className="linkactive";
}

function l_mark(cell)
{
for(i=0; i <
document.getElementById("up").getElementsByTagName("li")[0].length; i++)
{
document.getElementById("up").getElementsByTagName("li")[0][i].className="uplink-l";
}
cell.className="uplink-l-active";
}

function i_mark(cell)
{
for(i=0; i <
document.getElementById("up").getElementsByTagName("li")[1].length; i++)
{
document.getElementById("up").getElementsByTagName("li")[1][i].className="uplink-i";
}
cell.className="uplink-i-active";
}

window.onload = setActive;
</script>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Fyi, your code leaks a global `i`

Comment: I am new to javascript, i already tried to sum the whole code up but it didn't worked in the way it works now. But i know what you mean

Comment: I assume the code needs "If" conditions.

Comment: the global i let all elements get to change the background image ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Leistungen" has the class lmark, while "Impressum" has imark. Your Javascript function for lmark-classed elements resets the background for all other lmark-classed elements, but not for the imark-classed ones. Same for the function that concerns imark.

If you need to have only one non-default background for all lmark *and* imark elements, a correct (probably correct, though not tested) code is:

```
function li_mark(cell) {
    var elts=document.getElementById("up").getElementsByTagName("li"); //store the elements we need in a local variable so we don't have to rewrite all that line (and the browser won't have to do the fetching job again), we don't care if they're L-type or I-type
    for(var i in elts)
        if(elts[i].className && elts[i].className.length>=8) //check if there is a className and it is at least as long as "uplink-X", otherwise we don't process the element and skip to the next
            elts[i].className="uplink-"+elts[i].className.charAt(7); //we retrieve the letter for the type of class (L or I), and we append it to "upload-" to redefine the class of the current element
    cell.className+="-active"; //after the loop, all elements have their default class, so we just need to append "-active" to the one we want to be active
}
```

Then, all your calls to `l_mark(this)` and `i_mark(this)` should simply be replaced by calls to `li_mark(this)`.

P.S.: not related, but my current browser (Firefox) doesn't seem to like the `window.onload=setActive;`, saying that "setActive is not defined"...

**Edit according to comments**, having seen your JS file (`scripttests.js`):

You still need 2 functions, `mark()` and `li_mark()`, because for `mark()` your active class is of the form `<className>active` instead of `<className>-X-active` (not the same pattern in naming the classes, and no need to retrieve the character Lor I).

Another part of the problem is that you call `cell.className+="-active"` twice on the same cell in the one function you have.

The last part of the problem is that you forgot the instruction within the `if` of the second loop: as there are no block brackets, the instruction that is executed when this `if` is true is `cell.className+="-active"`...  executed as many times as the loop runs and the `if` is true.

A (probably) working version would be:

```
function li_mark(cell) {
    var elts=document.getElementById("up").getElementsByTagName("li"); //store the elements we need in a local variable so we don't have to rewrite all that line (and the browser won't have to do the fetching job again), we don't care if they're L-type or I-type
    for(var i in elts)
        if(elts[i].className && elts[i].className.length>=8) //check if there is a className and it is at least as long as "uplink-X", otherwise we don't process the element and skip to the next
            elts[i].className="uplink-"+elts[i].className.charAt(7); //we retrieve the letter for the type of class (L or I), and we append it to "upload-" to redefine the class of the current element
    if(cell && cell.className && cell.className.length>=8) { //if we passed an argument, then it must be a cell to activate, with a basic check on its className
        cell.className+="-active"; //after the loop, all elements have their default class, so we just need to append "-active" to the one we want to be active
        mark(); //we call mark() with no argument to reset all the items managed by mark(), we call it in this if-block to avoid infinite recursion
    }
}
function mark(cell) {
    var elts=document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("li"); //store the elements we need in a local variable so we don't have to rewrite all that line (and the browser won't have to do the fetching job again), we don't care if they're L-type or I-type
    for(var i in elts)
        if(elts[i].className) //check if there is a className, otherwise we don't process the element and skip to the next
            elts[i].className="link"; //we set back to the default class
    if(cell && cell.className) { //if we passed an argument, then it must be a cell to activate
        cell.className+="active"; //after the loop, all elements have their default class, so we just need to append "active" to the one we want to be active
        li_mark(); //we call li_mark() with no argument to reset all the items managed by li_mark(), we call it in this if-block to avoid infinite recursion
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks!! Its working for the second nav! But how to accomplish it to make the "Leistungen" link in the first nav get to change its background at the same time as when you click the link on the second nav? I would do this with an if-clause but i dont know how to implement it.

Comment: I have following Lines of Code as idea:

Comment: `var nav1=document.getElementById("nav").getElementsByTagName("li"); var nav2=document.getElementById("up").getElementsByTagName("li");`

Comment: **Updated my site with my interpretation of new code** [zp-kaz.html](http://enlifer.de/test25/zp-kazachkova.html)    there seem to be problems... the _-active_ part gets copied 5 or six times after clicking

Comment: Couldn't be used `document.getElementsByClassName('test');` ?

Comment: See the updated Answer for your issues. For getElementsByClassName(), in my opinion it should be avoided if possible, as it is slow for browsers to retrieve tags from the whole document, based on one of their class. Actually, I'm not even sure that getElementsByClassName is now part of the W3C standard (I used to code my own version of this function as it wasn't implemented by browsers).

Comment: Thank you very much! It seems to be now more understandable. But it has a problem with the second nav again. It doesn't do anything. If I delete the javascript for the first nav there isn't even a error message. So it seems it could be with the second if in li_mark, because the previous is the same as your last code. I updated the site again with the new script. // I do not know what the structure _if we passed an argument_ exactly means. Thanks!

Comment: You're right, there was an error in the conditional statement. It's written if(... && cell.className>=8) whereas it should be written if(... && cell.className.length>=8), as we check the size of the string contained in className, not its value.

Comment: About the if-block checking if cell exists, it's because now each function has 2 behaviors: either you don't give an argument to the function (just call "mark()") and it will set all the <li> items to their default class (no one active), or you give an argument (like mark(document.getElementById('someId')) and then we'll enter this if-block that activate the one element we passed as argument (cell.className+="active") **and** we'll reset **all** the other <li> items by calling the other function without argument (i.e. using the first behavior I explained above).

Comment: It is all right now, thanks for the pretty lines of code! The only thing that is now missing is that when the "_Leistungen_" link is clicked in the first navigation, the "Leistungen" link in the second navigation need also to be highlighted. The same when you click on the "_Leistungen_" link in the second nav -> "_Leistungen_" in the first nav will be highlighted. I tested this now for some time and I 1. do not know where to place the code (in mark or li_mark or to make a new function) and 2. which variables i need to declare.

Comment: I have updated the .js file, after line 28 you can see the test code: [ZP Kaz - script.js](http://enlifer.de/test25/script.js) .

Comment: In the code now it says `getAttributeNodeNS()` should not be used, instead `getAttributeNS()`; the same with `nodeName` `name` or `nodeName` `value`.

Comment: In your test code: document.getElementById returns one element, not an array, so you don't need the loop. Actually, you don't even need a function: in each function, in the if-block you previously didn't understand, you just need a condition after reseting the other <li> (i.e. after calling mark() or li_mark() without argument). This condition should be something like the following for mark: if(cell.id=='lsone') {li_mark(document.getElementById('lstwo'));} and same with alternate IDs for li_mark: if(cell.id=='lstwo') {li_mark(document.getElementById('lsone'));}

Comment: Thanks. It says the cell is undefined?

Comment: I can't tell what's wrong: I don't see any changes in your uploaded code :/

Comment: I uploaded the file. Now there isn't an error but there is also no function :/

Comment: Ah actually there is a bad recursion. Instead of using the alternate mark function, we should directly write: if(cell.id=='lsone') document.getElementById("lstwo").className="uplink-l-active"; and same for the other function: if(cell.id=="lstwo") document.getElementById("lsone").className="link-active"; In the current case, it's even weird that Javascript doesn't fire an error because of infinite recursion ("too much recursion" error) :)

Comment: I tried to rewrite the code, thought it was because of two times the same li_mark in the if clauses at the end. As soon as one was mark only the browser crashed after seconds of freezing :))

Comment: So much thanks!! Works now properly and fast. Amazing coder! Wonder for how long you are coding?

Comment: You're welcome :) And yes, the freezing was probably because of this infinite recursion... I tried to do it too fast ^^ To answer your wondering, I've been learning code for 6-7 years, including 3-4 years at school.

Comment: Nice :) , have only half a year knowledge (combined) but I know where to ask and search - for me its just copying understanding and hoping that its working :D